# Moving Chrome extension to Tampermonkey // Greasy Fork

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

Good night, everyone. I'm trying to move a chrome extension that consist basically on a script, to Tampermonkey, as a single script. But is not working. The script is as follow:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++) {
        try {
            if (details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'content-type' &&
                details.responseHeaders[i].value.toLowerCase() == 'application/x-forcedownload') {
                details.responseHeaders[i].value = "";
            }
            if (details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'content-disposition' &&
                details.responseHeaders[i].value.indexOf(".pdf") != -1) {
                details.responseHeaders[i].value = "";
            }
        } catch (err) { }
    }
    return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
}, {urls: ['*://*/*.pdf*']}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

And that's the manifest.json main lines

```
 "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": [ "code.js" ]
   },

"permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://*/*" ],
```

I've tried to just use the JS code on Tampermonkey, but it doesn't work properly, and I guess that I need to assure that Tampermonkey will have the same permissions as the manifest.json permissions.

Someone has any idea, of how to do that script work in Tampermonkey?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get that to work. You've got a [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) in the extension, and Tampermonkey runs the equivalent of content scripts. APIs such as `chrome.webRequest` are only available to background scripts.

Comment: Tampermonkey has its own GM_webRequest.